# Javascript: "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" error when trying to remove child

Tags: javascript, event-listener, removechild

Very new to javascript. I'm building a very simple website to showcase someone's portfolio. In the HTML, I have a link with the ID 'chocolate-link'. When I click the link, the addVideo function runs as expected.

I'm having trouble with the dismissVideo function. I want to be able to click the "close X" link in the video variable to remove the elChocolate variable. When the page loads, I get a "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" error in the console. Any help is appreciated.

Here's the javascript:

```
var video = '<div class=\"header\"><a id=\"close\" href="#">close X</a></div>';
video += '<iframe class="chocolate" src="[link here]" width="700" height="396" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>';

var elChocolate = document.createElement('div');
elChocolate.setAttribute('id', 'video');
elChocolate.innerHTML = video;

function addVideo() {
  document.body.appendChild(elChocolate);
  elAdd.className = "active";
}

var elAdd = document.getElementById('chocolate-link');
elAdd.addEventListener('click', addVideo, false);

function dismissVideo() {
  document.body.removeChild(elChocolate);
}

var elClose = document.getElementById('close');
elClose.addEventListener('click', dismissVideo, false);
```

Comment: It means that the thing you are trying to `addEventListener` is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is only adding the `close` element to the DOM upon click of `chocolate-link`, but you're trying to manipulate `close` immediately (before anyone clicks the link to add it) so it's failing.  You probably want to add the `close` click handler immediately after it's added to the DOM.  I would recommend adding it to the bottom of the `addVideo` function.

This code is attaching a click handler to the `addVideo` function, but `addVideo` won't get called until the link is clicked:

```
var elAdd = document.getElementById('chocolate-link');
elAdd.addEventListener('click', addVideo, false);
```

Immediately after, you call this code:

```
var elClose = document.getElementById('close');
elClose.addEventListener('click', dismissVideo, false);
```

That code is attaching a function to the 'close' button which isn't created yet.  You probably want to attach that function when the `addVideo` function is called.

Comment: That did the trick. I moved the elCose variable into the addVideo function, and added a line to the dismissVideo function to clear the link class. Thanks.